# How can I add the "SUM" aggregate to the "rcount" column in my SQL code below?

Tags: sql

```sql
SELECT 
  `a.film_title`, 
  `a.category_name`, 
  COUNT(`a.film_title`) AS `rcount` 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      `f.title` AS `film_title`, 
      c.name AS `category_name` 
    FROM 
      film f 
      JOIN `film_category` b ON `b.film_id` = `f.film_id` 
      JOIN category c ON `c.category_id` = `b.category_id` 
      JOIN inventory i ON `i.film_id` = `f.film_id` 
      JOIN rental r ON `r.inventory_id` = `i.inventory_id` 
      AND c.name in (
        'Animation', 'Children', 'Classics', 
        'Comedy', 'Family', 'Music'
      )
  ) a 
GROUP BY 
  1, 
  2 
ORDER BY 
  2, 
  1;
```

Comment: You should use named columns in your `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses.

Comment: Sample data would greatly help your question.

Comment: Why are you using `COUNT(a.film_title)` instead of `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: I feel your `c.name` predicate should be in a `WHERE` clause instead of being a `JOIN` condition.

Comment: What do you want to `SUM`? In your subquery `a`  I see no numeric candidate to to be SUM'ed... Consider providing more information of what you want to do and how is your data model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL has a bunch of quoting mistakes.  At the end of this post, you'll find one kind of `SUM` (window function) applied to your `COUNT(a.film_title)`.  You should clarify exactly what you wish to `SUM`.

If there's a specific `SUM` not shown below, update the given test case and explain the expected result you wish to generate, given the existing data.

and finally, if you just want to aggregate/`SUM` `rcount` per `category_name`:

```
SELECT category_name
     , SUM(rcount) AS srcount
  FROM (
          SELECT f.title        AS film_title
               , c.name         AS category_name
               , COUNT(f.title) AS rcount
            FROM film          f
            JOIN film_category b
              ON b.film_id      = f.film_id
            JOIN category      c
              ON c.category_id  = b.category_id
            JOIN inventory     i
              ON i.film_id      = f.film_id
            JOIN rental        r
              ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
             AND c.name IN (
                     'Animation', 'Children', 'Classics', 'Comedy', 'Family', 'Music'
                 )
           GROUP BY film_title   , category_name
       ) x
 GROUP BY category_name
 ORDER BY category_name
;
```

or just this, without the derived table:

```
SELECT c.name         AS category_name
     , COUNT(f.title) AS rcount
  FROM film          f
  JOIN film_category b
    ON b.film_id      = f.film_id
  JOIN category      c
    ON c.category_id  = b.category_id
  JOIN inventory     i
    ON i.film_id      = f.film_id
  JOIN rental        r
    ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
   AND c.name IN (
           'Animation', 'Children', 'Classics', 'Comedy', 'Family', 'Music'
       )
 GROUP BY category_name
 ORDER BY category_name
;
```

Result:

```
+---------------+---------+
| category_name | srcount |
+---------------+---------+
| Animation     |       5 |
| Children      |       2 |
| Comedy        |       1 |
+---------------+---------+
```

**Updated** ([with test case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9a01bf56fce3795263931a09641f8c1c)) to show (`cat_sum`), which is the `SUM` of `rcount` over all `films` for each `category` within the current result:

```
SELECT f.title        AS film_title
     , c.name         AS category_name
     , COUNT(f.title) AS rcount
     , SUM(COUNT(f.title)) OVER (PARTITION BY c.name) AS cat_sum
  FROM film          f
  JOIN film_category b
    ON b.film_id      = f.film_id
  JOIN category      c
    ON c.category_id  = b.category_id
  JOIN inventory     i
    ON i.film_id      = f.film_id
  JOIN rental        r
    ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
   AND c.name IN (
           'Animation', 'Children', 'Classics', 'Comedy', 'Family', 'Music'
       )
 GROUP BY film_title   , category_name
 ORDER BY category_name, film_title
;
```

Result with test data:

```
+------------+---------------+--------+---------+
| film_title | category_name | rcount | cat_sum |
+------------+---------------+--------+---------+
| film1      | Animation     |      2 |       5 |
| film2      | Animation     |      3 |       5 |
| film1      | Children      |      2 |       2 |
+------------+---------------+--------+---------+
```

and slightly different `SUM`(s) with more data:

```
-- `SUM` of the `COUNT` (rcount) for all `category` for this film

SELECT f.title        AS film_title
     , c.name         AS category_name
     , COUNT(f.title) AS rcount
     , SUM(COUNT(f.title)) OVER (PARTITION BY c.name)  AS catsum_per_cat
     , SUM(COUNT(f.title)) OVER (PARTITION BY f.title) AS catsum_per_title
  FROM film          f
  JOIN film_category b
    ON b.film_id      = f.film_id
  JOIN category      c
    ON c.category_id  = b.category_id
  JOIN inventory     i
    ON i.film_id      = f.film_id
  JOIN rental        r
    ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
   AND c.name IN (
           'Animation', 'Children', 'Classics', 'Comedy', 'Family', 'Music'
       )
 GROUP BY film_title   , category_name
 ORDER BY category_name, film_title
;
```

Result:

```
+------------+---------------+--------+----------------+------------------+
| film_title | category_name | rcount | catsum_per_cat | catsum_per_title |
+------------+---------------+--------+----------------+------------------+
| film1      | Animation     |      2 |              5 |                4 |
| film2      | Animation     |      3 |              5 |                3 |
| film1      | Children      |      2 |              2 |                4 |
| film3      | Comedy        |      1 |              1 |                1 |
+------------+---------------+--------+----------------+------------------+
```

Here's an update to your SQL with errors corrected, plus a simplified version expressing the same logic.  Feel free to use this to update or create a new question.

```
SELECT a.film_title
     , a.category_name
     , COUNT(a.film_title) AS rcount
  FROM (
          SELECT f.title   AS film_title
               , c.name    AS category_name
            FROM film          f
            JOIN film_category b
              ON b.film_id      = f.film_id
            JOIN category      c
              ON c.category_id  = b.category_id
            JOIN inventory     i
              ON i.film_id      = f.film_id
            JOIN rental        r
              ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
             AND c.name IN (
                   'Animation', 'Children', 'Classics', 'Comedy', 'Family', 'Music'
                 )
       ) a
 GROUP BY a.film_title   , a.category_name
 ORDER BY a.category_name, a.film_title
;
```

The above SQL can be simplified to this:

```
SELECT f.title        AS film_title
     , c.name         AS category_name
     , COUNT(f.title) AS rcount
  FROM film          f
  JOIN film_category b
    ON b.film_id      = f.film_id
  JOIN category      c
    ON c.category_id  = b.category_id
  JOIN inventory     i
    ON i.film_id      = f.film_id
  JOIN rental        r
    ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
   AND c.name IN (
           'Animation', 'Children', 'Classics', 'Comedy', 'Family', 'Music'
       )
 GROUP BY f.title      , c.name
 ORDER BY category_name, film_title
;
```

Please provide a clear description of what you would like to `SUM` and a simple example of the output you wish to generate.  There are several potential problems in the way you are aggregating based on the joins.

This test case might help review those issues:

[Working test case.   Adjust for your specific database.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9a01bf56fce3795263931a09641f8c1c)

If you have access to window functions, you can use `SUM` in the following way, just as an example.

```
SELECT f.title        AS film_title
     , c.name         AS category_name
     , COUNT(f.title) AS rcount
     , SUM(COUNT(f.title)) OVER () AS xsum
  FROM film          f
  JOIN film_category b
    ON b.film_id      = f.film_id
  JOIN category      c
    ON c.category_id  = b.category_id
  JOIN inventory     i
    ON i.film_id      = f.film_id
  JOIN rental        r
    ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
   AND c.name IN (
           'Animation', 'Children', 'Classics', 'Comedy', 'Family', 'Music'
       )
 GROUP BY f.title      , c.name
 ORDER BY category_name, film_title
;
```

Comment: My code earlier generates output of the number of times the category_name appears for the film. So I want to sum the rcount for each category_name('Animation', 'Children', 'Classics', 'Comedy', 'Family', 'Music') in output for visualization.